# Creating a minimized overlapped window (Win32)

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'd like to create an overlappedwindow that starts out visible (so the taskbar button shows) but minimized.  Creating the window with WS_MINIMZED (or WS_MAXIMIZE for that matter) does nothing.  Using ShowWindow(hWnd,SW_SHOWMINIMIZED) gives a critical error.  I suspect it has something to do with STARTUPINFO but I can't find any info on how to adjust/change/hijack it.

```
hWnd = CreateWindowA(
    (LPCSTR)atom, 
    "Window Name", 
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE | WS_MINIMZED,    // doesn't work
    CW_USEDEFAULT, 
    CW_USEDEFAULT, 
    CW_USEDEFAULT, 
    CW_USEDEFAULT, 
    0, 
    0, 
    hInstance, 
    0);

ShowWindow(hWnd,SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);    // gives critical error
```

Comment: showing a window minimized is fine. Problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Don't make us guess what "critical error" looks like.  Just plain WS_OVERLAPPED and ShowWindow with SW_SHOWMINIMIZED will do.

Answer (score 0):

@Kaisha, you are right: if you start an executable using CreateProcess, then the visibility of the window will be influenced by STARTUPINFO. To start an application with its window minimized, do this:

```
ZeroMemory(&startupInfo, sizeof(startupInfo));
startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
startupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
startupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE;
```

I used this approach in an application which repeatedly started the command-line version of WinZip, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Citing the MSDN, function `ShowWindow`, parameter `nCmdShow`:

> Controls how the window is to be shown. This parameter is ignored the first time an application calls ShowWindow, if the program that launched the application provides a STARTUPINFO structure.

So I'm guessing that your window is the first window created by the application, and as such, the parameter of `ShowWindow` is ignored.

Another little known fact is seen in the docs for `CreateWindow`, parameter `y` (yes, `y`):

> If an overlapped window is created with the WS_VISIBLE style bit set and the x parameter is set to CW_USEDEFAULT, then the y parameter determines how the window is shown. If the y parameter is CW_USEDEFAULT, then the window manager calls ShowWindow with the SW_SHOW flag after the window has been created. If the y parameter is some other value, then the window manager calls ShowWindow with that value as the nCmdShow parameter.

Probably it is better if you create the window hidden (without `WS_VISIBLE`) and/or passing 0 as the `y` parameter of `CreateWindow`.

Other options would be to create a dummy window first, show it, and destroy it quickly, some like a splash-screen. That would consume the STARTUPINFO command.

Comment: Better than creating a dummy window would be just calling `ShowWindow` twice on the main window.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes but, ah, the flicker!

Comment: I don't remember if this "feature" affects `HideWindow` and `ShowWindow`, you could probably create the main frame without `WS_VISIBLE`, minimize it (twice), then show it.